# can't complie xcode project because missing info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I have a project that is running fine on one of my computers. When I copy that project to another machine I get the following message "reading data: The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
". I checked that the file is there. I tried clean then build but nothing happens. I also tried to check the info.plist path by checking project--->build settings---> packaging--->info.plist. I am sure it is correct but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be in a specific path not anywhere inside the project , so if your files look like this

[image]

drag it inside the folder , and delete the red one that will show inside project hierarchy after the Moving

also a better solution is to copy it outside , then remove the file from the project and finally drag it again with copy checked

//

packaging should look like this

```
 projectName/Info.plist
```

[image]

also follow the error path

[image]

Comment: it is not outside it is inside a folder in the project and I specified it path in info.plist path by checking project--->build settings---> packaging but it is still not working

Comment: don't specify any static paths as this may be the problem , let it figure where it's as it's an expected issue with multiple pcs

Comment: I didnot specify I just checked it is the correct path where it is located and it is the correct path